# Is there an alternative for MessageQueueMatcher.receivesPayloadThat in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I recently switched to the new test binder for Spring Cloud Stream. In my project I updated to the latest Spring Cloud Stream version 3.1.3
After removing the spring-cloud-stream-test-support dependency the MessageQueueMatcher.receivesPayloadThat matcher is not available anymore. Is there a new matcher or an alternative matcher with a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we decided not to overcomplicate things. You send a Message, you receive one back and you assert using the tools already available by the testing framework you use.